# Laravel query nested relationship on same table

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a users table whose basic structure looks like:

```
id, uname, parent_id  
1   john    null  
2   smith   1  
3   mickey  1  
4   lara    2  
5   tom     3  
6   jessica 4  
7   baneet  4
```

and relationship in user model is defined like :

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', 'parent_id');
}

public function parents()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'parent_id');
}
```

So, what I am trying to do is: find all users whose children have no children. 
In Lehman terms: Find all families who have children but their children don't have any children.

I know how to do it when I just have to query immediate relationship like

```
User::whereHas('children',function($query){
           // $query;
        })->get();
```

But not sure how to do in the nested relationship.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User::whereHas('children', function($query) {
    $query->whereDoesntHave('children');
})->get();
```

Shorter but a bit counterintuitive:

```
User::doesntHave('children.children')->get();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but for some weird reason 
whereDoesntHave is not working. it still returns the same result when my query is User::whereHas('children')->get();


Moreover even in query log whereDoesntHave is not getting executed.

Comment: Query Log Part 1: 
0 => array:3 [▼ "query" => "select from `users` where exists (select from `users` as `laravel_reserved_0` where `users`.`id` = `laravel_reserved_0`.`parent_id` and `laravel_reserved_0` ▶" "bindings" => [] "time" => 1.8 ] 1 => array:3 [▼ "query" => "select * from `users` where `users`.`parent_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null" "bindings" => array:9 [▼ 0 => 3 1 => 40 2 => 41 3 => 44 4 => 45 5 => 47 6 => 52 7 => 55 8 => 56 ] "time" => 0.73 ]

Comment: Query Log Part 2: 
2 => array:3 [▼ "query" => "select * from `users` where `users`.`parent_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null" "bindings" => array:23 [▼ 0 => 40 1 => 41 2 => 42 3 => 43 4 => 44 5 => 45 6 => 46 7 => 47 8 => 48 9 => 49 10 => 50 11 => 51 12 => 52 13 => 53 14 => 54 15 => 55 16 => 56 17 => 57 18 => 58 19 => 59 20 => 60 21 => 61 22 => 62 ] "time" => 1.27 ]

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: Try the second query from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change some on your Model
Like this

```
public function children(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', 'parent_id')->with('children');}public function parents(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'parent_id')->with('parents');}
```